# Offer codes not working in live appstore app when entering with presentCodeRedemptionSheet()

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

When calling the SKPaymentQueue.default().presentCodeRedemptionSheet() method on live appstore app it will present redemption sheet and after entering the promo code in it is displaying 'Cannot connect' screen as seen in attached picture[this is after entering the code instead of showing me code benefits associated with subscription plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QckZm.jpg). What could be the reason for this and what solutions can be found to solve the problem? please some one help it is really frustrating.

https://i.ibb.co/BChSQgq/IMG-52-EDEB1596-F8-1.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, pretty sure it's something on Apple's end